# How do I use/create a db cursor in my python thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, multithreading, jaydebeapi

I'm getting threading errors when I try to use or create a db cursor in my process_id function. Each thread will have to use the database to process data for their passed id.

I can't utilize a cursor in the thread/process_id at all(I get threading errors and the DB never updates)...I've coded it a lot of different ways. The code works when I don't use threads.

I have very specific requirements for how this code is to be written, slow and stable is fine. I also cut out a lot of error handling/logging before posting. Daemon/Infinite loop is required.

How do I spin up a new cursor in each thread?

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import jaydebeapi, sys

#Enter the values for you database connection
database = "REMOVED"          
hostname = "REMOVED"
port = "REMOVED"               
uid = "REMOVED"       
pwd = "REMOVED" 

connection_string='jdbc:db2://'+hostname+':'+port+'/'+database

if (sys.version_info >= (3,0)):
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", connection_string, [uid, pwd], jars="REMOVED")
else:
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", [connection_string, uid, pwd])

# Thread Pool Variables
max_threads = 5
used_threads = 0

# define main cursor
cus=conn.cursor()

def process_id(id):
    #create a cursor for a thread
    cus_id=conn.cursor()
    cus_id.execute("SOME QUERY;")
    cus_id.close()
    global used_threads
    used_threads = used_threads - 1         
    return 0

def daemon():
    global num_threads, used_threads
    print("Daemon running...")
    while True:
        #ids to process are loaded into a list...
        for id in ids_to_process:
            if used_threads < max_threads:
                t = threading.Thread(target=process_id, args=(int(id),))
                t.start()
                used_threads += 1
    return 0

daemon()
```

Comment: Did you try that code using JayDeBeApi>=1.2.1. It solves some threading related issues.

Comment: Why do you have that distinction between sys.version_info >= 3,0?